# Dynamically instantiating linked object chain

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, abstract-class, instantiation

I am implementing a chain of command pattern for a substring search. I can create the chain statically by writing something like this:

`matchChain = new CharMatcher( new DotMatcher( new CharMatcher(null)));`

where I explicitly declare what each character in the string is going to be to match the pattern Character Period Character `("c.c")`

But my goal is to dynamically create this chain for any given key pattern. For example `` ("\`\`cccc.cc\`\`*c") `` would be:

`matchChain = new CharMatcher( new CharMatcher( new CharMatcher( new CharMatcher( new CharMatcher(new DotMatcher( new CharMatcher( new CharMatcher( new StarMatcher( new CharMatcher(null)))))));`

So the Chain class is an abstract class and each of the matcher classes extend Chain.

So how can I dynamically instantiate a chain based off of the length of the given key/pattern?

Comment: you need to manually write the code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a builder method<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
public class ChainBuilder {

    private static final char DOT ='.', STAR = '*';

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pattern = "cccc.cc*c";
        Chain chain = chainBuilder(pattern);

        //printout chain structure
        String space ="", step =" ";
        while (true){
            if(chain == null){
                System.out.println(space + chain);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(space + chain.getClass().getSimpleName());
            space += step;
            chain = chain.getNextLink();
        }
    }

    private static Chain chainBuilder(String pattern){

        Chain chain = null;
        String reversePattern = new StringBuilder(pattern).reverse().toString();
        for(char c : reversePattern.toCharArray()){

            switch (c) {
            case DOT:
                chain = new DotMatcher(chain);
                break;
            case STAR:
                chain = new StarMatcher(chain);
                break;
            default:
                chain = new CharMatcher(chain);
                break;
            }
        }
        return chain;
    }
}


class Chain {

    private final Chain nextLink;

    public Chain(Chain nextLink) {
        this.nextLink = nextLink;
    }

    public Chain getNextLink() {
        return nextLink;
    }
}

class CharMatcher extends Chain{

    public CharMatcher(Chain nextLink) {
        super(nextLink);
    }
}

class DotMatcher extends Chain{

    public DotMatcher(Chain nextLink) {
        super(nextLink);
    }
}

class StarMatcher extends Chain{

    public StarMatcher(Chain nextLink) {
        super(nextLink);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup>
The posted code is an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Copy-paste the entire code into `ChainBuilder.java` and run.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I have been trying to figure out.

Comment: You are welcome. A recursive implementation is also possible.

Comment: What would be the proper way to break the chain say if a condition is not met. Ex. if we have the pattern "ABC.DEF". and the string ACXYZ. So A and B exist but C doesnt so we want to break the chain/search and return an error.

Comment: This question is about creating a chain. You are asking an entirely different question, about using the chain. I am not sure I understand how it is being used. Please ask a new question and leave me a message here. I recommend posting an mre that shows how you use it.